# How to redirect http access by ip or domain name to an https domain name?

Tags: nginx

After configuring my Web server, when accessing via IP or domain name, https redirects are performed as follows:

`http://192.168.10.5 to https://192.168.10.5`

`http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com`

However, I want http://192.168.10.5 and http://www.example.com to be redirected to https://www.example.com.

Basic Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  192.168.10.5 www.example.com;

    location / {
            rewrite     ^(.*)   https://$http_host$1 permanent;
    }
}

server {

    listen      443 http2 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

     root /var/www/example/html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key;

   }
```

Comment: Replace `$http_host` with the correct domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  server_name  192.168.10.5 www.example.com;

  location / {
        rewrite     ^(.*)   https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen      443 http2 ssl;
  server_name 192.168.10.5;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key;

  location / {
        rewrite     ^(.*)   https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen      443 http2 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  root /var/www/example/html;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as this web application server is a custom solution, I think there must be other settings that make it difficult to redirect the way I want.

I did what was suggested and the redirect hasn't changed. I believe that in a non-customized installation, the above suggestion should work perfectly.

Comment: Did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: You were right, after clearing the cache it was possible to redirect from `http://192.168.10.5` to `https://example.com`. However due to some wrong configuration it is not possible to redirect from `https://192.168.10.5` to `https://example.com`. Do you know how to solve this case too?

Comment: With the correct configuration much more is possible. See my edit.

Comment: When making the settings and running the command systemctl restart nginx.service , it gave an error. Checking with the journalctl -xe command, I saw the following messages: `nginx: [warn] the "ssl" directive is deprecated, use the "listen ...`
`nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ...`
`Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.`

Comment: I've added the ssl_certificate for 192.168.10.5 server.  If this still doesn't work, I'd try without the "server_name 192.168.10.5;" line.

Comment: I am very grateful to Gerard for his help. I knew very little about Nginx settings. You made it possible to solve the problem and allowed me to learn a little more. I will certainly use this knowledge in future configurations.

Although the solution, I believe there is a conflict of SSL certificates. I will check this problem with the company that markets the system.

Comment: Who is trying to access this system using an IP address?   I don't think you can have a certificate for an IP address.  Perhaps you can accept my answer?

Comment: The redirect issue has been resolved. I accepted your answer.